# react-native run-android fails

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

Since I've upgraded to react-native 0.42.0, I can't run my app anymore.

I've got a weird issue where instead of getting react-native from node_modules, gradle will get the old version 0.21 from maven repository. I've tried freezing the version, suppressing everything build or cache related and I've even start fresh by copying only js files. But I still encounter errors related to gradle not looking in node_modules for react-native.

Here's my settings.gradle :

```
rootProject.name = 'My App'

include ':app'
include ':react-native-google-analytics-bridge'
project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-analytics-bridge/android')
```

and my app's build.gradle dependencies :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.42.0"  // From node_modules
    compile "com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.11.0"
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
}
```

and finally the project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            url "http://private-repos"
        }
    }
}
```

Any clue ?

Comment: what version were you using before? If it's a few versions old then there might have been breaking changes.

Comment: I've already made all changes listed in the changelog. I think it ran once or twice before I opened it in android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "http://private-repos"
        }
    }
}
```

You have to create a maven section for each url you want to add.
It never even throws an error when you specify it like I did first, it simply ignores the first url.
Hours lost because of improper logging ...

Answer (score 0):

**Try to check the package.json and see what's in there.**

If you find the old version there, you can change it then run `npm install` or just run `npm install --save react-native@<the-desired-version>`

If you get an error that you need to upgrade react then run
`npm install --save react@<needed-version>`

In my case I had to use this alternative because the standard one(based on git) didn't work.

More details about this alternative and the standard one here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

Comment: I've got the correct version in my packages.json same goes for react. I can see it in my node_modules but it is not used when building.